# MongoDB collection to .Net dictionary best practice

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have an application that performs fast operations on in-memory data. This data is represented in memory as a `Dictionary<MyKey,MyData>`. The `MyKey` is a class that contains a few string tags:

```
public class MyKey
{
    string tag1;
    string tag2;
    ... 
}
```

and `MyData` is an object that contains some texts.

I would like to store it in MongoDB as a collection of documents like:

```
{
    tag1: "foo1",
    tag2: "foo2",
    mydata: { ... }
},
{
    tag1: "bar1",
    tag2: "bar2",
    mydata: { ... }
}...
```

so that I can use mongodb selectors:

```
db.MyCollection.find({tag1: "foo1"})
```

But then it becomes really annoying to write the serializer / deserializer, since a one-to-one mapping would do:

```
{
    mykey: { tag1: "foo1", tag2: "foo2"},
    mydata: { ... }
}
```

I feel like this is a pretty common issue. What is the best solution to achieve this?
I want to keep the original Dictionary structure but I don't want to reinvent the wheel for the Serializer.

Any idea / tutorial I could follow?
Is this even something I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no issue with document of this form:

```
{
    mykey: { tag1: "foo1", tag2: "foo2"},
    mydata: { ... }
}
```

You can still query it.

```
db.collection.find({'mykey.tag1': 'foo1'})
```

Does this answer your question? Is there another particular reason for wanting that document structure?

Comment: ah really? And it doesn't imply any speed loss?